# Router page not opening

Tags: router

When I try to access my router page at `192.168.0.1` (my default gateway) I get the folowing error message:

[image: My Error]

I haven't changed anything in my router's configuration recently and I'm pretty sure that `192.168.0.1` is the default gateway. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is not programming related

Comment: "pretty sure" or positive about that gateway? Do an ipconfig (looks like you are using windows, but can't tell for sure) and see. 192.168.1.1 is equally common these days for routers.

Comment: I did and I'm "positive" that it is 192.168.0.1

Comment: Have you tried a different computer or browser?

Comment: did you try cleaning the cache of your browser?

Comment: @connor W
yes I have and all give the same results

Comment: you could run the following in cmd: ipconfig/release and after that is done ipconfig/renew

Comment: the last thing you can try is to restart your router and see what happens then

Comment: or doing a reset where you stick a pin in, and hold until perhaps lights change, could be 10sec, could be 30sec.. I have seen a router where holding it a bit longer did a fuller reset where all settings cleared. for better or worse. your router manufacturer will know about resetting it. and obviously, ipconfig to see ip and ipconfig /release and ipconfig /renew

Comment: @darius You should post your comment as an answer so you can earn the reputation you deserve for fixing the problem.

Comment: @Connor W - How long does it usually take for new person to realize that they should credit a person that have solved their problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can try the following in a Command Prompt:

```
ipconfig /release
```

After this is done, type the following:

```
ipconfig /renew
```

If the above did not work you should restart your router and try to access the router
webpage again.

P.S. If the problem persists it might be a time for a new router.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a home router, have you tried removing it's power for 30 seconds and reconnecting power?