# Can't get to router page

Tags: networking, router

So, I go to cmd, and see that my default gateway is 10.0.1.1 I type this in to my address bar, and get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.` Pinging the router works.

Image of error:

[image]

I had a look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/278089/router-page-not-opening) answer, but `ipconfig /release` yields the following: `No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection while it has its media disconnected.`

Zoom cable modem router, win7

EDIT;

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Fleet-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : socal.rr.com

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : socal.rr.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Linksys WUSB600N Dual-Band Wireless-N US
 Network Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1E-E5-E3-26-1D
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8d36:32e1:5f40:449a%15(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.1.4(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, August 24, 2014 11:53:49 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Monday, August 25, 2014 11:53:49 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 234888933
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-16-6C-43-5A-00-19-D1-88-58-0

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : socal.rr.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82566DC-2 Gigabit Network Conne
tion
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-19-D1-88-58-0B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.socal.rr.com:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : socal.rr.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:90d7:34d4:67e0:5305:554f(Pre
erred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::34d4:67e0:5305:554f%12(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

EDIT, AGAIN: Turned out I wasn't plugging into the router directly, but rather the wireless, which was then plugged into the router. Just a bit of cable confusion.

Anyway, I plugged directly into the router, but couldn't get any internet at all. I let windows try and fix it, and it gave me this:

[image]

Comment: What are you using that router for? It's a class A network address, quite strange for a SOHO setup. Could you post `ipconfig /all` output?

Comment: @gronastaj, there really aren't "classes" anymore. the mask is 255.255.255.0, so it is a /24 network, which is actually fairly common for SOHO networks. Do you get any different behavior when you connect using a cable? do you just type the address in, or do you preface it with http://?

Comment: Tried both of each - direct cable/wireless, with http:// and without.

Comment: Something interesting to note is that when I go into the airport utility (for wireless) I can port-forward (I tested it - it works), something I thought you were suppose to do on the router page.

Comment: Oh, and it (the airport utility) also says that the subnet mask is 255.255.240.0, which contradicts ipconfig /all.

Comment: Whoops, cable mistake - see edit to question.

Comment: What makes you think your cable modem has user-configurable settings?